# how to get app service(azure) custom domain ip address using terraform?

Tags: azure, dns, terraform, ip

I want to use Terraform to get the ip address. Does anyone know it?

azure app service's custom domain ip address

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can export the IP address assigned to the hostname if IP based is SSL enabled using **virtual_ip** argument in **azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding**

The custom domain IP address can be accessed by the following reference:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service_custom_hostname_binding#virtual_ip

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately, virtual_ip actually provides an empty value.

At the moment, outbound seems to be the best.

Reference : https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/14385

Comment: Are you looking for inbound ip address or outbound ip address?

Comment: I'm looking for an inbound ip address.

Comment: We cannot get the inbound ip address using terraform. If your custom domain is mapped to your web app, you can get the ip address using virtual_ip